# running batch file within powershell

Tags: batch, powershell, batch-file, batch-rename

I'm running a batch file within PowerShell. It calls up another program to do a bunch of maps which it outputs to a subfolder called "GRD"

I then want to rename the files in the GRD folder by adding spaces " " where there are underscores "_", so I'm using the PoweShell command:

> DIR | Rename-Item -NewName { $*.name -replace "*"," " }

This line works fine if I type it into the PS command window after I've run my batch file. But is there a way that I could incorporate this line into the end of my batch file? I've tried:

> cd GRD
>
> DIR | Rename-Item -NewName { $*.name -replace "*"," " }

But i get the error:

> C:\Data\GRD>DIR  | Rename-Item -NewName { $*.name -replace "*"," " }
>
> 'Rename-Item' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Why are you trying to make a batch file, and not a powershell script? (ps1)

Comment: @Zoredache: originally a batch file was sufficient for my task of generating maps. With the output file names not being exactly right, I read that using PowerShell could do the name change. Pls keep in mind I'm not an expert and just learning my way through.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that your example doesn't work properly at all, in general to use PowerShell form a batch file you specify that you want to run PowerShell, and feed the PS command-line to it as an argument.

So in your batch use something like:

`powershell "DIR | Rename-Item -NewName { $.name -replace \"\",\" \" }"`

Note the `\` in front of the double-quotes to escape them inside the argument delimiting double-quotes.

Comment: does not seem to work. I get the error: 'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.